# How to create a torrent file with multiple files in Java?

Tags: java, torrent

I am currently trying to implement a small tool which creates a `.torrent` from a set of files inside a folder. It works perfectly fine for single files.

According to this site: [Torrent_file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torrent_file#Multiple_files) multiple files are stored inside a file set.

Here is what I have done so far:

```
public Map<Object, Object> getFiles(File dict) throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {

    Map<Object, Object> files = new HashMap<Object, Object>();
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(merged);

    for (File fileEntry : dict.listFiles()) 
    {
        if (fileEntry.isFile()) 
        {
            Map<String, Object> file = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            file.put("path", fileEntry.getName());
            file.put("length", fileEntry.length());

            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fileEntry);
            byte[] byteArray = new byte[(int) fileEntry.length()];
            fis.read(byteArray, 0, (int) fileEntry.length());
            fos.write(byteArray);
            fos.flush();
            files.put(file.get("path"), file.get("length"));
        }

    }
    fos.close();
    pieces = hashPieces(merged, pieceLength);
    return files;
}
```

I try to create a map for each individual file and then put these maps into another map containing all files. Then I am merging the files as file arrays into one big file for calculating the pieces hash. However, the file structure part does not work as supposed.

The method for multiple files is called by:

```
    // ...
    Map<String, Object> info = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    info.put("name", sharedFile.getName());
    if (sharedFile.isDirectory()) {
        Map<Object, Object> path = getFiles(sharedFile);
        info.put("files", path);
    }
    // ...
```

Somehow I don't know how to assemble the file list. I know it has to be done with a map, but I am desperate about what I have to choose as key and value.

Comment: Wikipedia is a terrible source for technical information about the BitTorrent protocol. Try https://wiki.theory.org/BitTorrentSpecification#Metainfo_File_Structure instead.

Answer (score 0):

The value under the `files` key in the info map is not a map, it is a list of maps, which each map describing one file.